# {"_csharpnull" : true} as document in one of the property. What does it mean?

Tags: mongodb, serialization, deserialization

I am using C# driver 2.8 of Mongodb to serialize a C# object to Mongdb db with version 3.4.9.

In some of the documents saved I get this document {"_csharpnull" : true} , I dont know why such document gets created by C# driver. And when I try to desrerialize it ofcourse it does not work.

An example of the saved document

```
  { 
      "_id" : "LINESTEST/YA11", 
      "Metadata" : {
          "LockMetadata" : {
              "_csharpnull" : true
          }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### BsonValues serialization

This is expected when having `LockMetadata == null` in the C# side if we assume that your parameter `LockMetadata` is of type `MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue`, or anything derived from it like `BsonDocument`, in your C# model (or represented as, [see documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.5/reference/bson/mapping/#representation)),

The code `LockMetadata .ToBsonDocument()` will serialize into `_csharpnull` and will appear as follow under the mongodb server:

```
"yourObjectProperty" : {
    "_csharpnull" : true
},
```

More reading about this here: [How should BsonValues be serialized for C# null?](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-863)